# Android Studio stuck on loading screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-7, java-6

Every time I run Android Studio, this loading screen pops up, but Android Studio stays here and doesn't load. It's like this following picture except that the loading bar is loaded all the way but stuck there. I am running Windows 10.

[image]

I have tried many things, including setting the system variables `JDK_HOME` to where my `JDK` is located and the same for `JAVA_HOME`. I have also set a path. I ran as admin many times and let AS through a firewall.

I have also restarted and reinstalled countless times.

**The version of AS is 2.0**, and I am running the latest versions of Java.

Any help?

Comment: Uninstall AS, remove AS setting and Use java JDK 7 and try again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Open file Android Studio setup **directory/bin/idea.properties**
- Add **`disable.android.first.run=true`** to end
- Restart Android Studio

> PLEASE NOTE: This will break patch updating to the next version. We
>   now check full binary checksums on the whole installation to prevent
>   various install corruption bugs as well as to preserve application
>   signatures. Therefore, make a copy of this file first, and before
>   updating, put it back.

Comment: It does not allow changes to be made

Comment: I tried to edit it but when I tried to save it didn't allow the change to be made

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting very frustrated for a couple of hours and you just made my night and school in the morning :D

Comment: You just saved my life!

Comment: thank you a LOT! But... what does this mean/change exactly?

Comment: go to the installation directory of Android Studio. There you will find a folder named bin. Inside this folder there is a file named idea.properties. Open this file and add the following line to the end of the file:@swalkner

Comment: @AmitVaghela yes, I got that, it helped. What I mean: what does this property mean/change exactly? Just would like to know what I'm doing.

Comment: it will disable the check that Android Studio performs on first run and decides to download all that stuff@swalkner

Comment: @AmitVaghela Thanks this works for me with AndroidStudioPreview3.6

Comment: still working 6 years later :D

Comment: @AmmarMohamed Good to know.

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following method to fix that issue:

1. Find the folder of your AndroidStudio: based on the following directory

macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio[version]

2. Delete the AndroidStudio folder.
3. Restart

Ref:https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories

Answer (score 0):

In order to know *how* to debug the problem, I executed the **`bin\studio.bat`** script in the terminal and inspected the actual Idea exceptions in order to fix the problem.

For me, this was the issue:

```
ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

This means the plugin manager is trying to listen on a port that is not available.  Is something listening on that port?  For me, it was the stupid "excluded ports" by Windows, so I simply stopped the service:
**`net stop winnat`** (as administrator), and confirmed that Android Studio started to work.

No need to re-install, delete precious configuration (and plugins, etc.). Just read the log provided by the **`bin\studio.bat`** script, and I was able to fix the issue.