# android studio loading but it is not opening further

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Every time I run Android Studio, this(below .jpg image) loading screen pops up, but Android Studio stays here and doesn't load. It's like this following picture except that the loading bar is loaded all the way but stuck there. I am running Windows 10.
[image: below is the .jpg image which shows the loading position of android studio]

I have tried many things, including setting the system variables JDK_HOME to where my JDK is located and the same for JAVA_HOME. I have also set a path. I ran as admin many times and let AS through a firewall.

I have also restarted and reinstalled countless times.
I am running the latest version of Java.

I got an answer of adding the line "disable.android.first.run=true" in the end of the file which is located in  Android Studio setup directory/bin/idea.properties.
It is opening the page where we have to choose from creating a new project,existing project,import etc.
But when I choose a new project or any other options, it says your sdk is corrupted or you have an older version and then it starts to update it.
But it's not getting updated because of "disable.android.first.run=true" this line which prevents it from updating.
Also I am not able to locate the path of my sdk in the configure sdk option as it is not responding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio stuck on loading screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474669/android-studio-stuck-on-loading-screen)

Answer (score 0):

## New Version?

- Have you tried to uninstall it and install the latest version of Android Studio that was released? [(3.0)](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjw1dDPBRC_ARIsAJZrQfoBWJPcRmelqx303_5imkaXZ6RGoSDAEId1AJYMj4Sgjv-uQ5J9rdAaAg1CEALw_wcB)
- Or maybe you updated to the last version and it's incompatible for some reason and you can try and install the latest stable version (before 3.0) wich is 2.3.3 if I am not wrong. [(Click here to go to the AS Archive)](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html)

Comment: I have tried installing version 2.3.3 as well as version 3.0 , both of them are causing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**wait** for some time it's probably **downloading** latest **Gradle zip** behind the scenes, which you can disable after loading from settings. if you have started the studio from the terminal you can see there if it's downloading something. Be patient and have a good connectivity is the way to solve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have reset my laptop and then installed the android studio, and now it is working perfectly fine. Thank you guys for the suggestions.

Comment: reset laptop? like how?