# Android Studio 4.1 Stuck at loading screen in Mac

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, flutter

My Android Studio has been stuck at loading screen since yesterday. X_X

[image]

What I have tried:

1. Restarting computer.
2. Clearing junk files and logs.
3. Completely uninstall and then Reinstalling AndroidStudio.
4. Followed many different solutions (e.g: one of it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474669/android-studio-stuck-on-loading-screen)). But still doesn't work. Excerpt from the solution:

- Open file Android Studio setup directory/bin/idea.properties
- Add `disable.android.first.run=true` to end
- Restart Android Studio

5. When I deleted the SDK it worked, but then after I let it download the SDK again, it opens for that session, then stuck again on the next session.

Well, I don't want to always delete and re-download the SDK every time I open Android Studio. So does anyone have any solution to this?

Thanks

More Info:

```
Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.6
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 4029M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin, Dart, io.flutter
```

My `jave -version`

```
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+14, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version`

```
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
```

My `studio.vmoption`:

```
-Xms1G
-Xmx4G
-XX:MaxPermSize=1G
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=
-Didea.vendor.name=Google
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_studio_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_studio.hprof
```

My `idea.properties`:

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500
idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024
sun.java2d.d3d=false
idea.dynamic.classpath=false
idea.no.launcher=false
idea.xdebug.key=-Xdebug
sun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=true
swing.bufferPerWindow=true
idea.fatal.error.notification=disabled
javax.swing.rebaseCssSizeMap=true
idea.max.content.load.filesize=20000
idea.popup.weight=heavy
sun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false
CVS_PASSFILE=~/.cvspass
com.apple.mrj.application.live-resize=false
java.endorsed.dirs=
idea.smooth.progress=false
apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories=true
apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
apple.awt.fullscreencapturealldisplays=false
idea.jre.check=true
disable.android.first.run=true
```

Comment: Run android studio in the terminal too see any errors logged. Just drag the Android Studio app icon into Terminal with your mouse.

Comment: If I just drag it to the terminal it gives this error: `-bash: /Applications/Android Studio.app: Is a directory`. Then I tried to run the `studio.sh` from the `bin/` directory. But strangely enough there is no `studio.sh`. I tried to reinstall it but there is still no `studio.sh`

Comment: Have a look at this guide https://www.wikihow.com/Open-Applications-Using-Terminal-on-Mac

Comment: I just tried it, there is no error message. I can see the next command prompt but the Android Studio still stuck

Comment: More info, so after I did step 5 in the question, although it can work but Android Studio does not open any welcome screen or any project. Nothing. I need to right click on the icon at the bottom of the screen to select 'Recent project'. And once again, I need to reinstall SDK every time.. so annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me somehow:

1. I managed to get it open first by tricking it (deleting SDK and re-downloading it as I have stated in the question).
2. Go to Help => Change memory settings. Then change the Maximum Heap Size to 4096
3. Press Save and Restart

I don't know why it works and whats the cause of my problem. But this is a quick fix.
If anybody knows, please enlighten me.

Thanks

Update:
I fixed the problem. It seems that it it was caused by plugins or sdk problem. In my case it was the Flutter package. Probably or somehow the installation on my machine had a problem and possibly Android studio tried to load it and got stuck. Somehow switching channels and doing `flutter upgrade` then reinstalling flutter plugins. Solved it for me.
So probably just a pointer: see if there is any sdk / plugins installation problem

Answer (score 5):

Delete Folder

For Windows:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1
```

For MacOS:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1
```

Comment: Works perfect for me!!

Comment: Try not to delete all versions directories because you might end up losing your settings, I kept 1 old version and updated latest one, then migrated everything to new one. It has worked for me at macbook.

Answer (score 2):

If above method not work just delete all cache from Caches folder and restart Android Studio.

```
MacOS: ~/Library/Caches/
```